# If one knows Homotopy Type Theory, what is the easiest way to learn Higher Topos Theory?

Tags: topos-theory, homotopy-type-theory

Just read Lurie's book? Do there exist any papers which explain higher topos theory with an audience of homotopy type theorists in mind?

Comment: I'm definitely not an expert in either area, but given how young HTT is, I can't imagine that there are expositions of many areas aimed specifically at homotopy type theorists.

Comment: I used three resources to learn higher topos theory: 1) Lurie's book, 2) Rezk's overview article at http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~rezk/homotopy-topos-sketch.pdf and 3) I spent lots of hours reading the nlab.